# How to conda install CUDA enabled PyTorch in a Docker container?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, anaconda, pytorch

I am trying to build a Docker container on a server within which a conda environment is built. All the other requirements are satisfied except for CUDA enabled PyTorch (I can get PyTorch working without CUDA however, no problem). How do I make sure PyTorch is using CUDA?

This is the `Dockerfile` :

```
# Use nvidia/cuda image
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

# set bash as current shell
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash

# install anaconda
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 git mercurial subversion && \
        apt-get clean
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh && \
        /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
        rm ~/anaconda.sh && \
        ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
        echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        find /opt/conda/ -follow -type f -name '*.a' -delete && \
        find /opt/conda/ -follow -type f -name '*.js.map' -delete && \
        /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy

# set path to conda
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH


# setup conda virtual environment
COPY ./requirements.yaml /tmp/requirements.yaml
RUN conda update conda \
    && conda env create --name camera-seg -f /tmp/requirements.yaml \
    && conda install -y -c conda-forge -n camera-seg flake8

# From the pythonspeed tutorial; Make RUN commands use the new environment
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "camera-seg", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

# PyTorch with CUDA 10.2
RUN conda activate camera-seg && conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch

RUN echo "conda activate camera-seg" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/camera-seg/bin:$PATH
```

This gives me the following error when I try to build this container ( `docker build -t camera-seg .` ):

```
.....

Step 10/12 : RUN conda activate camera-seg && conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
 ---> Running in e0dd3e648f7b
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(34): Subprocess for 'conda run ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'conda activate camera-seg && conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch']' command failed.  (See above for error)

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.



The command 'conda run -n camera-seg /bin/bash -c conda activate camera-seg && conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is the `requirements.yaml`:

```
name: camera-seg
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - numpy
  - pillow
  - yaml
  - pyyaml
  - matplotlib
  - jupyter
  - notebook
  - tensorboardx
  - tensorboard
  - protobuf
  - tqdm
```

When I put `pytorch`, `torchvision` and `cudatoolkit=10.2` within the `requirements.yaml`, then PyTorch is successfully installed but it cannot recognize CUDA ( `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `False` ).

I have tried various solutions, for example, [this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123637/activate-conda-environment-in-docker/62674910#62674910) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123637/activate-conda-environment-in-docker/62674910#62674910) and some different combinations of them but all to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any ideas on how to solve this *without* installing torch with pip?

Comment: @rubencart You can install all the dependencies using conda within the requirements file and for torch and torchvision, make an entry within Dockerfile explicitly. For example, add this line in Dockerfile after the line installing the `requirements.yaml` dependencies: `RUN conda install -y -n ${CONDA_ENV_NAME} -c pytorch pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 ipython`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got it working after many, many tries. Posting the answer here in case it helps anyone.

Basically, I installed `pytorch` and `torchvision` through `pip` (from within the `conda` environment) and rest of the dependencies through `conda` as usual.

This is how the final `Dockerfile` looks:

```
# Use nvidia/cuda image
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

# set bash as current shell
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# install anaconda
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 git mercurial subversion && \
        apt-get clean
RUN wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/anaconda.sh && \
        /bin/bash ~/anaconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
        rm ~/anaconda.sh && \
        ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
        echo ". /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc && \
        find /opt/conda/ -follow -type f -name '*.a' -delete && \
        find /opt/conda/ -follow -type f -name '*.js.map' -delete && \
        /opt/conda/bin/conda clean -afy

# set path to conda
ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH


# setup conda virtual environment
COPY ./requirements.yaml /tmp/requirements.yaml
RUN conda update conda \
    && conda env create --name camera-seg -f /tmp/requirements.yaml

RUN echo "conda activate camera-seg" >> ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/camera-seg/bin:$PATH
ENV CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV $camera-seg
```

And this is how the `requirements.yaml` looks like:

```
name: camera-seg
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.6
  - pip
  - numpy
  - pillow
  - yaml
  - pyyaml
  - matplotlib
  - jupyter
  - notebook
  - tensorboardx
  - tensorboard
  - protobuf
  - tqdm
  - pip:
    - torch
    - torchvision
```

Then I build the container using the command `docker build -t camera-seg .` and PyTorch is now being able to recognize CUDA.

Comment: Any thoughts on doing it for Cuda 11.0?  I am tempted to try your solution adjusting for 11.0 but unsure if I want to enter the rabbit hole :)

Comment: One thing I hadnt realized is that conda installs its own cuda so no need to worry about versioning so much.  This solution worked fine for me.

Comment: @JohnCurry did you manage to get everything working? You also don't need to install torch and torchvision with pip. It can be installed using conda by having an statement within the Dockerfile. See my comment in the question. For a different cuda version, I am assuming just changing `cudatoolkit=11.0` should work along with a change in the very first line in the Dockerfile: `FROM nvidia/cuda:11.0-cudnn.....` . I have not tried it myself though.

Comment: yes all works fine.  I didn't change to 11.0 in the end as the code I'm using requires 10.2 in any case. Really useful image, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I managed to set it up with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-devel-ubuntu20.04
ENV TZ=Europe/Brussels

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
   build-essential \
   python3 \
   python3-dev \
   python3-pip

RUN pip install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

I made sure the cuda version is the same as installed on the machine where the docker container would be running.

Then I did docker build and run as follows:

```
$ docker build . -t docker-example:latest
$ docker run --gpus all --interactive --tty docker-example:latest
```

Inside the docker container, inside a python shell, `torch.cuda.is_available()` would then return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Check nvidia drivers are installed  :

```bash
nvidia-smi -a
```

if not working try  :

```bash
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g')
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$distribution/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-drivers
```

> ## Note :  Reboot your os after this installation

#### Install nvidia docker run-time on you machine  :

```bash
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
distribution="ubuntu22.04"
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/$distribution/nvidia-container-runtime.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit
echo -e  '{\n    "default-runtime": "nvidia",\n    "runtimes": {\n        "nvidia": {\n            "path": "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime",\n            "runtimeArgs": []\n        }\n    }\n}' > /etc/docker/daemon.json
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Verify nvidia is setup for the docker  :

```bash
sudo docker info | grep Runtime
```

## code for docker file :

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.8.0-runtime-ubuntu22.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y locales
RUN localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG=en_US.utf8
RUN export LANG=en_US.utf8

##################################################
#           install dependecies                  #
##################################################
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget git build-essential nano unzip curl 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y g++



##################################################
#           install conda                        #
##################################################
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
RUN bash miniconda.sh -b -p /miniconda
RUN rm miniconda.sh
ENV PATH="/miniconda/bin:${PATH}"
RUN echo 'export PATH="/miniconda/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /miniconda/bin/conda config --set auto_activate_base true
RUN /miniconda/bin/conda init

##################################################
#           install PYTORCH                      #
##################################################
RUN /miniconda/bin/conda  install -y pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia

##################################################
#           install code-server                  #
##################################################
RUN curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh

##################################################
#                  CMD                           #
##################################################
EXPOSE 5001
CMD code-server --bind-addr 0.0.0.0:5001 --auth none /home
```