# How to Start a Conda Environment with Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, shell, conda, environment

I am a `docker` novice, so apologies if this is a silly question.

As background, I am using a docker image that I have no ability to edit or change. I run the container with `docker run [various-args] [image-name]` and the container is launched. If I subsequently run `docker exec -it [ID] bash`, I can get a shell going from inside the container and it successfully executes a `conda` environment needed for all my python code, so I can just run `python script.py` and everything runs okay.

I wanted to automate this process for future use, so I wanted to put these commands into a single script so that I don't need to manually type or execute anything from within the environment. The solution I thought would work was this:

```
docker exec -it [ID] bash -c "python script.py"
```

but this doesn't work, giving an import error for the python code. My assumption is that the conda environment is not activated, so I try to execute `conda activate my-env`, which kicks back a new error of:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
```

So, I follow the instructions and run `conda init bash` first to see if that helps, but this error still kicks back eventually. Ultimately, it seems like if I execute a bash shell first, then manually start running python code everything is fine, but if I try to do it all at once the conda environment cannot be set up for somme reason. Is there a way to make this work without editing the image itself, or is this something that would require rebuilding the image?

Thanks ins advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conda activate` function is defined by code added to `.bashrc` by the `conda init` command. Bash will not source `.bashrc` unless the `-l` (`--login`) flag is used.

However, rather than bothering with shell, Conda provides a `conda run` command that executes within a specified environment. So, try something like

```bash
docker exec -it [ID] conda run -n my-env python script.py
```

For interactive scripts, one may also need some of the additional `conda run` flags, such as `--live-stream` or `--no-capture-output`. See `conda run -h`.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your answer! Sorry for responding late; I was working this solution for a bit to see if it could work. You approach doesn't spit back any errors, which is great, but the console after the docker image is created. After I `^C` to cancel out, I see that I canceled out of a conda command and get a `CondaError`. Do you now why this might be?

Comment: @JoshB. have you tried running with the `--live-stream` flag? Sounds to me like it is running, but you're just not seeing the I/O until you kill it (which is what `conda run` does by default).

Comment: So, after some experimentation, i learned that the `--live-stream` flag is not an available flag for this version of conda within the docker image, so I just let it run for a while to see if the command was saving the files it was intending. After checking inside the container manually, I found that the command was working, even though there was no console output, but it was running exceptionally slowly (about 60x slower than if I had done this manually). Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: @JoshB. Not really. I’ve never had noticeable performance degradation with `conda run` but I also haven’t used it for long-running ops. Could be something specific with the old version of Conda. This probably merits a new question.

Comment: So long story short, I have found that the version of `conda` within the docker image is the version _just prior_ to when the `--live-stream` flag was added, which is a bummer. This still doesn't explain why executing a bash environment within the docker then running the script gives an output but running it all from the outside doesn't, nor why it runs so slowly. I have settled on this approach for now, but ultimately I can't seem to figure out why these issues are happening.

Comment: Also possible to define the "conda run ..." in the **ENTRYPOINT*, as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148365/6812182