# Conda-lock not working, just returns help info on my MacOS (Sonoma)

Tags: conda, miniconda, conda-lock

I want to use conda-lock as described in kxmh42's answer to [Does it make sense to use Conda + Poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851048/does-it-make-sense-to-use-conda-poetry).

However, no matter what combination of command line options I use, I just get the help info dumped. No locks are created.

I've tried using both conda-lock from conda-forge (as described in the Stackoverflow answer above) and conda-lock from HomeBrew (I tried this way because my conda was originally installed through brew). But no matter what I try, I get the same result.

What's going on here?

`test % conda-lock lock -k 'explicit' --log-level DEBUG
Usage: conda-lock lock [OPTIONS]

Generate fully reproducible lock files for conda environments.

By default, a multi-platform lock file is written to conda-lock.yml.

When choosing the "explicit" or "env" kind, lock files are written to
conda-{platform}.lock. These filenames can be customized using the
--filename-template argument. The following tokens are available:

```
  platform: The platform this lock file was generated for (conda subdir).
  dev-dependencies: Whether or not dev dependencies are included in this lock file.
  input-hash: A sha256 hash of the lock file input specification.
  version: The version of conda-lock used to generate this lock file.
  timestamp: The approximate timestamp of the output file in ISO8601 basic format.
```

Options:
--conda TEXT                    path (or name) of the conda/mamba executable
to use.
--mamba / --no-mamba            don't attempt to use or install mamba.
--micromamba / --no-micromamba  don't attempt to use or install micromamba.
-p, --platform TEXT             generate lock files for the following
platforms
-c, --channel TEXT              Override the channels to use when solving
the environment. These will replace the
channels as listed in the various source
files.
--dev-dependencies / --no-dev-dependencies
include dev dependencies in the lockfile
(where applicable)
-f, --file PATH                 path to a conda environment specification(s)
-k, --kind TEXT                 Kind of lock file(s) to generate [should be
one of 'lock', 'explicit', or 'env'].
--filename-template TEXT        Template for single-platform (explicit, env)
lock file names. Filename must include
{platform} token, and must not end in
'.yml'. For a full list and description of
available tokens, see the command help text.
--lockfile TEXT                 Path to a conda-lock.yml to create or update
--strip-auth                    Strip the basic auth credentials from the
lockfile.
-e, --extras, --category TEXT   When used in conjunction with input sources
that support extras/categories
(pyproject.toml) will add the deps from
those extras to the render specification
--filter-categories, --filter-extras
In conjunction with extras this will prune
out dependencies that do not have the extras
specified when loading files.
--check-input-hash              Check existing input hashes in lockfiles
before regenerating lock files.  If no files
were updated exit with exit code 4.
Incompatible with --strip-auth
--log-level [DEBUG|INFO|WARNING|ERROR|CRITICAL]
Log level.
--pdb                           Drop into a postmortem debugger if conda-
lock crashes
--virtual-package-spec PATH     Specify a set of virtual packages to use.
--update TEXT                   Packages to update to their latest versions.
If empty, update all.
--pypi_to_conda_lookup_file TEXT
Location of the lookup file containing Pypi
package names to conda names.
--md, --metadata [timestamp|git_sha|git_user_name|git_user_email|input_md5|input_sha]
Metadata fields to include in lock-file
--with-cuda TEXT                Specify cuda version to use in virtual
packages. Avoids warning about implicit
acceptance of cuda dependencies. Ignored if
virtual packages are specified.
--without-cuda                  Disable cuda in virtual packages. Prevents
accepting cuda variants of packages. Ignored
if virtual packages are specified.
--mdy, --metadata-yaml, --metadata-json PATH
YAML or JSON file(s) containing structured
metadata to add to metadata section of the
lockfile.
--help                          Show this message and exit.`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. `conda-lock` didn't work until the `environment.yaml` file was created.

Try to execute:

```
conda env export | grep -v "^prefix: " > environment.yml
conda-lock -k explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer from Robin Loxley's comment in [Does it make sense to use Conda + Poetry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70851048/does-it-make-sense-to-use-conda-poetry):

conda lock has updated, replacing

```
conda-lock -k explicit --conda mamba
```

with following

```
conda-lock -f environment.yml -p linux-64 -p <if any> --conda mamba
```