# Docker Image with Conda Env Activated and Ready for Shell Commands

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I have tried many ways through searching for a solution.

I think my problem is different.

I am wanting to have a docker image that has the environment installed and then active and ready for shell commands like: flake8, pylint, black, isort, coverage

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Create the environment:
COPY conda_env_unit_tests.yml .
RUN conda env create -f conda_env_unit_tests.yml
RUN echo "conda activate up-and-down-pytorch" >> ~/.bashrc
```

conda_env_unit_test.yml

```
name: up-and-down-pytorch
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - pytest
  - pytest-cov
  - black
  - flake8
  - isort
  - pylint
```

.gitlab-ci.yml (slimmed down)

```
stages:
  - docker
  - linting
  - test

build_unit_test_docker:
  stage: docker
  tags:
    - docker
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: "miniconda3-up-and-down-unit-tests"
  script:
    - cp /builds/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/conda_env_unit_tests.yml /builds/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/docker/unit_tests/
    - docker -D login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    - docker -D build -t $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/$IMAGE_NAME docker/unit_tests/
    - docker -D push $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/$IMAGE_NAME
  rules:
    - changes:
      - docker/unit_tests/Dockerfile
      - conda_env_unit_tests.yml

unit-test:
  stage: test
  # image: continuumio/miniconda3:latest
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/miniconda3-up-and-down-unit-tests
  script:
    # - conda env create --file conda_env.yml
    # - source activate up-and-down-pytorch
    - coverage run --source=. -m pytest --verbose
    - coverage report
    - coverage xml
  coverage: '/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
```

The Docker Image gets uploaded to the gitlab registry and the unit test stage uses that image, however:

```
/bin/bash: line 127: coverage: command not found
```

(ultimate goal was to not have to create the conda environment every time I wanted to lint or run unit tests)

Comment: Can you use an ordinary Conda environment, or even a plain Python virtual environment?  (Why is it important that you use Docker to run this shell in an isolated environment without access to host files?)

Comment: if I understand you correctly, it is because it will be faster if the environment is already setup instead of creating it from scratch every time? Sorry if I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: One of Docker's core features is that containers can't normally see host files, and _vice versa_.  Conversely, Python already has pretty good features for separating applications' library trees from each other.  So I'm wondering if you can use an ordinary Python virtual environment for these sorts of developer tasks, and take Docker out of the picture entirely.

Comment: The flip side of this is that keeping a Conda or plain-Python virtual environment "activated" in Docker is a little tricky, since each `RUN` command launches a new shell and dotfiles like `.bashrc` aren't normally read.  Some of the answers to [Activate conda environment in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123637/activate-conda-environment-in-docker) describe the workarounds required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out today.
Dropped the duration for the unit tests.

Change was to source the environment in the unit-test job. Didn't need to do that in the Dockerfile.

Dockerfile

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# Create the environment:
COPY conda_env_unit_tests.yml .
RUN conda env create -f conda_env_unit_tests.yml
```

conda_env_unit_tests.yml

```
name: up-and-down-pytorch
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - pandas
  - pytest
  - pytest-cov
  - black
  - flake8
  - isort
  - pylint
```

.gitlab-ci.yml (slimmed down)

```
stages:
  - docker
  - linting
  - test

build_unit_test_docker:
  stage: docker
  tags:
    - docker
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    IMAGE_NAME: "miniconda3-up-and-down-unit-tests"
  script:
    - cp /builds/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/conda_env_unit_tests.yml /builds/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/docker/unit_tests/
    - docker -D login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
    - docker -D build -t $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/$IMAGE_NAME docker/unit_tests/
    - docker -D push $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/$IMAGE_NAME
  rules:
    - changes:
      - docker/unit_tests/Dockerfile
      - conda_env_unit_tests.yml

unit-test:
  stage: test
  image: $CI_REGISTRY/upanddown1/mldl/up_and_down_pytorch/miniconda3-up-and-down-unit-tests
  script:
    - source activate up-and-down-pytorch
    - coverage run --source=. -m pytest --verbose
    - coverage report
    - coverage xml
  coverage: '/(?i)total.*? (100(?:\.0+)?\%|[1-9]?\d(?:\.\d+)?\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
```

Comment: I have a question about this approach: don't you get race conditions? Like if I have multiple pipelines going at once, possibly on different branches, don't these images conflct? The images don't seem to be unique to a pipeline or anything, at least that I can see, so won't you just get the latest one regardless of what branch it comes from? Would like to know how this works if I am wrong.