# Restart bash in dockerfile for conda install

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, conda

I am trying to create a dockerfile for the PI2 project https://github.com/learnedinterfaces/PI2 and have created the following docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
# Update and set locale
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.utf8
# Install npm and wget
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt install -y npm wget
# Install miniconda
RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh 
RUN bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ~/miniconda3 
RUN rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
RUN ~/miniconda3/bin/conda init bash
# Create and activate conda env
RUN conda create -n pi --override-channels --strict-channel-priority -c conda-forge -c nodefaults jupyterlab=3 cookiecutter nodejs jupyter-packaging git
RUN conda activate pi

# Clone PI2 git
RUN mkdir PI2
RUN git clone https://github.com/learnedinterfaces/PI2.git --depth 1 --branch=master PI2
# Enter PI2 dir
RUN cd PI2
# Set up pi-client
RUN cd pi-client
RUN npm install .
RUN npm run build
RUN npm run build-library
RUN jlpm link
RUN cd ..
# Set up pi-jupyter
RUN cd pi-jupyter
RUN npm install .
RUN jlpm link pi-client
RUN jlpm run build
RUN cd ..
# Set up server
RUN cd pi-server
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# Start server
RUN python server.py
EXPOSE 8000
```

The issue I am running into is for the installation of conda; when regularly installing on linux I would need to restart the terminal instance in order to use the conda command, however I am unsure of how to do that for the dockerfile. I have tried adding

```
SHELL ["bash", "-lc"]
```

or

```
RUN PATH="$PATH"
RUN exec bash
```

or

```
RUN bash -c "source ${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

But none of these have worked and conda is still not found. Is there any way that I am not recognizing to restart bash so it can recognize the conda command?

Comment: Why not start from something like [a Micromamba Docker image](https://micromamba-docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? Most users do not need a **base** environment, so you're jumping through a ton of hoops unnecessarily.

Comment: Each `RUN` command launches a new shell (and technically a new container); you don't need to "restart the shell".  Conversely, most paths to running commands in Docker don't read shell dotfiles, so editing the `.bashrc` is usually ineffective.  Are you really trying to [Activate conda environment in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123637/activate-conda-environment-in-docker)?

Comment: (Similarly note that `RUN cd ...` is a no-op, since the current directory at the end of the `RUN` line isn't persisted.  The line that starts the server probably wants to be the image's default `CMD` and not something you `RUN` during the build.)