# Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate' on dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, anaconda

I am making anaconda3 environment with docker.

However it shows the error like this below.

I guess it is related with some shell problem.. but I can't fixed yet.

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

My dockerfile is here.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install emacs wget
RUN wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN /bin/bash Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda3
RUN echo 'export PATH=/root/anaconda3/bin:$PATH' >> /root/.bashrc 

#RUN source /root/.bashrc
RUN . /root/.bashrc
RUN /root/anaconda3/bin/conda init bash
RUN /root/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n py37 python=3.7 anaconda
RUN /root/anaconda3/bin/conda activate py37
```

Comment: Why do you need an anaconda environment in a docker container?

Comment: @C.Nivs it makes installing python versions and packages predictable

Answer (score 7):

I believe your issue may be that you are sourcing your `.bashrc` on a separate line from the commands that rely on it. From the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

This means that your are sourcing your `.bashrc` in one layer (the first `RUN` line), then `RUN`ning the `conda` command in a **new** layer, one which doesn't know anything about environment in the previous layer.

Try something like this:

```
RUN . /root/.bashrc && \
    /root/anaconda3/bin/conda init bash && \
    /root/anaconda3/bin/conda create -n py37 python=3.7 anaconda && \
    /root/anaconda3/bin/conda activate py37
```

By running them all on one line, you're running them in a single layer.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, could you tell what is the "RUN . /root/.bashrc" for ?

Comment: The original error was "Your shell has not been properly configured". That configuration is done in the `.bashrc` file, so we run that first.

Comment: Do subsequent execution commands need to be in the same RUN line?

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this in [quite a bit easier way](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-conda-dockerfile/), if you place just one command `SHELL ...` in your Dockerfile after creation your venv like this:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./environment.yml .
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "venv", "/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY . .
```

[This stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74414247/12236467) helps you if you want to use conda with the *docker-compose* util.

Comment: This way worked for me; the one from @Kryten did not